# What does `std::move` on a predicate lambda mean?

Tags: c++, thread-safety, condition-variable

I am reading through https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/wait_for and there is the line:

```
return wait_until(lock, std::chrono::steady_clock::now() + rel_time, std::move(stop_waiting));
```

How is the `std::move` to be understood, or rather, what does it protect against?

On a second note, the page says the `return wait_until(..` is equivalent to `wait_for`. Really with the `return`? Or did they mean a simple, direct equivalence of both functions, implicitly referring to the absolute timepoint they create within the param list?

Comment: *"the page says the `return wait_until(..` is equivalent to `wait_for`"* -- Other way around.  The page says `wait_for` is equivalent to a certain `wait_until`. And even though "equivalent" is normally symmetric, you cannot flip things in this case because the `wait_for` declaration defines some of the identifiers in the `wait_until` expression. (Plus, omitting some details, `bool wait_for(X rel_time) { return wait_until(now() + rel_time); }` makes sense, but `return wait_until(now() + rel_time); { bool wait_for(X rel_time); }` does not.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The predicate could be an object which is expensive to copy. Here's an example:

```
std::vector<std::string> v(1'000'000); // A large vector

... // Fill the vector with actual data

// The vector is then moved inside the predicate closure object.
// This avoids the copy of the vector.
auto predicate = [v = std::move(v)](std::string s) -> bool {
    return s == v[2];
};

// Pass the predicate by move, so that the vector is not copied.
some_predicate_using_function(std::move(predicate));
```

Now, if `some_predicate_using_function` makes a copy of its predicate argument, the vector is then copied which is inefficient. Using `std::move` once again prevents that copy.

Moreover, the closure could even not support copies at all, e.g., when it captures a type that can not be copied like a `unique_ptr`.

For these reasons functions using predicate objects should attempt at avoiding copies when possible. (This is also true in general: template functions dealing with unknown, potentially large or non-copyable objects should avoid copies.)

Comment: And captured values can happen not to be copyable at all, e.g. if `v` in the example is `std::unique_ptr`. So, function call without `move` will not even compile.

Comment: Thank you! I was a bit confused at first because I didn't know that C++ doesn't allow a sole simple `bool` to be a predicate - `std::move` on that would leave it in an undefined state, which would of course make no sense (or cause big problems) for shared variables. A last little question: *when* is the capture executed? Has `v` been moved away in the following line or only when the lambda executes?

Comment: @Vroomfondel It's moved away immediately at the line `auto predicate = ....`.